# Plotting a scatterplot in R of a gene against 2 different conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

I have a seurat object and want to compare the expression level of X gene between cancer fibroblast and normal fibroblast as well? E.g., a scatter plot with x = gene vs y = gene in a specfic cell-type

I know you can plot a scatterplot within Seurat using this command:

```
FeatureScatter(cells4, feature1 = "gene1", feature2 = "gene2")
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to compare between datasets? A scatterplot implies _pairs_ of values, i.e., for each value of _x_ there is a corresponding value of _y_, and you plot a point for each of those pairs of coordinates. If the subsets don't match, even if the number of values of _x_ and _y_ is the same, by chance, the plot is meaningless.

Comment: I want to compare the values, the comparison between normal vs. cafs. Trying to compare the expression values between each.

Comment: Do you mean the _frequency_ of each value on each subset?

Comment: If you want to compare _distribution_ of GLI2 levels on each subset, I'd do something like `plot(density(as.vector(gli2_normal_fibr)), col = "red"); lines(density(as.vector(gli2_caf)), col = "blue")`

Comment: I want to compare the expression level of GLI2 between cancer fibroblast and normal fibroblast

Answer (score 1):

A scatterplot consists of (x,y) pairs of values, and the points must represent something. When single cell data is presented with scatterplots, each dot is usually a cell, as in the plot produced by `FeatureScatter()`. For comparing two groups of cells, Seurat has other plotting functions, like `VlnPlot()`.

```
VlnPlot(cells4, features = "GLI2")
```

If you have more clusters in the data besides the ones you want to plot, you can first subset them in the same object.

```
fibr_subset <- subset(cells4, idents = c("Normal Fibr","CAFs"))
```

Take a look at the [Seurat visualization vignette](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/visualization_vignette) for more examples on how to plot data.